# SQL method to get rid of redundant linked server querying

Tags: sql, sql-server

Instead of querying linked servers like this:

```
select * from LINKED_SERVER_1.dbo.account where enabled = true
UNION ALL
select * from LINKED_SERVER_2.dbo.account where enabled = true
UNION ALL
select * from LINKED_SERVER_3.dbo.account where enabled = true
UNION ALL
select * from LINKED_SERVER_4.dbo.account where enabled = true
UNION ALL
select * from LINKED_SERVER_5.dbo.account where enabled = true
```

I would like to have a method that takes `linked server` parameter and returns the data. Pseudocode would look like this:

```
function get_disabled_accounts(LS LINKED_SERVER)
{
    return (select * from LINKED_SERVER.dbo.account where enabled = true)
}

select * from get_disabled_accounts(LINKED_SERVER_1)
UNION ALL
select * from get_disabled_accounts(LINKED_SERVER_2)
UNION ALL
select * from get_disabled_accounts(LINKED_SERVER_3)
UNION ALL
select * from get_disabled_accounts(LINKED_SERVER_4)
UNION ALL
select * from get_disabled_accounts(LINKED_SERVER_5)
```

Is it possible to do in SQL? And whats more - I dont want to create any functions in database, I only want to have those "functions", or "methods" in my code.

Comment: only if you use dynamic SQL. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/linked-servers/pass-variable-linked-server-query

Comment: Of course, you simply create a view that encapsulates the UNION ALL query, and maintain that in one place

Comment: Unrelated: I note you ask quite a few questions, but accept few answers.